# DOMXPath Query for a dynamic HTML

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Suppose that i have this HTML from a source (scrapping it) :

```
<tr class="calendar_row" data-eventid="41675">
    <td class="alt2 eventDate smallfont" align="center"/>
    <td class="alt2 smallfont" align="center">9:00pm</td>
    <td class="alt2 smallfont" align="center">AUD</td>
    <td class="alt2 icon smallfont" align="center">
         <div class="cal_imp_medium" title="Medium Impact Expected"/>
    </td>
    <td class="alt2 eventHigh smallfont" align="center">
         <div class="calendar_detail level_1" data-level="1" title="Open Detail"/>
    </td>

    //I want to get this part below correctly

    <td class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont" align="center">0.2%</td>
    <td class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont" align="center"/>
    <td class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont" align="center">
        <span class="revised worse" title="Revised From -0.3%">-0.4%</span>
    </td>
</tr>​
```

And I want to get the value (nodeValues) of the td's through XPath :

```
$query = $xpath->query('//tr[@data-eventid="41675"]/td[@class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont"]');
```

I cant figure it out why im only getting the value **-0.4%**.
Though the html seems to be complicated and regradless of how it is being formatted, is there any possible way (query) to retrieve the values in between tags including the null ones on the second td?

Full Code

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc    = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath  = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query_results = $xpath->query('//tr[@data-eventid="'.$data_eventid.'"]/td[@class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont"]');
foreach($query_results as $values){
    if($values->nodeValue!=' ' and $values->nodeValue!='' and $values->nodeName!='#text') { //Discards Empty Arrays
        $table_values[$data_eventid][5] = $values->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, you're getting the *span*?  What are you using to create that query?  Are you using simplexml or one of the other built-in parsers?

Comment: i am using xpath query..and yes.i dont know why it gets the values of span..

Comment: Through [which one of the **thirteen different XML extensions**](http://php.net/refs.xml)?  DOM?  XMLParser?  SimpleXML?  Show us the code you use to define `$xpath`.

Comment: Im using DOM XPath..sorry i got confused..

Comment: You're only getting -0.4% in your $query_results or in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `//tr[@data-eventid="41675"]/td[@class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()`

Well you probably just want the nodes, so take the `/text()` off:

```
//tr[@data-eventid="41675"]/td[@class="alt2 pad_left eventHigh smallfont"]/descendant-or-self::*
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath matches three `td` elements, the first contains `0.2%`, then there is an empty one, and the last one contains `<span class="revised worse" title="Revised From -0.3%">-0.4%</span>`.

You assign in sequence the values of these nodes (skipping the empty ones) to the same variable `table_values[$data_eventid][5]` - that so will contain the value of the last (non-empty) node - i.e. `-0.4%`

If you want the values of all the nodes you should append them to a list, or place them in different elements of an array.